# How long will you be drinking your tea for?

Tags: future-constructions, future-continuous, future

Your friend is drinking (a cup of) tea. You know she'll be free after that.
You want to know how long she'll be engaged in this (so that you know when she'll be free).

Please tell me which of these options are possible and which are not.

- 1. How long will you be drinking your tea for?
- 2. How long will you drink your tea for?
- 3. How long until you've drunk your tea?
- 4.1. How long until you've finished drinking your tea?
- 4.2. How long until you've finished your tea?
- 4.3. How long until you've finished?
- 5. How long until you're finished?
- 6. How long until you're done?

I'm particularly interested in example 1 and 2.
*(Please, if you decide to comment on which option is the best, be sure to have gone through the possibilities/impossibilities of the options already offered.)*

Comment: Neither of the first two are natural for normal contexts. They imply that drinking tea is an "extended" activity like sleeping, visiting friends, or watching a movie. Just ask ***When will you be free**?* and stop hassling her!

Comment: None of them is obviously 'wrong' (I agree with FF that (1) and (2) sound especially unnatural) - but surely you _know_ roughly how long it takes to have a hot drink?

Comment: @KateBunting - I can take an hour to drink a mug of Nescafé - I quite like it when it has grown cold, much to the horror of my wife.

Comment: I think maybe OP's example context isn't a very good one, but a common  ***generic*** phrasing for this situation is ***Will you be much longer**?* That would normally imply *...because **I'm waiting for you*** (We'll just have to hope that @MichaelHarvey is prepared to chug down his lukewarm coffee quickly, rather than make us wait another 50 minutes for it to become enjoyably stone-cold! :)

Comment: What makes #1 unnatural to my AmE ear is the specific context, since this sounds natural, if colloquial, to me:  *How long will you be needing the rental for?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, instead of saying a meaningless "and stop hassling her!", you could have done a better job of explaining why 1 and 2 you think are "unnatural".
I can't see what's wrong with them. Someone is doing something, e.g. drinking tea, he's been doing so for fifteen minutes by now, and you want to know how long is left. Will _"how much longer"_ make them more natural for you? Like, "How much longer will you be playing tennis? (The person has been playing tennis for 20 minutes now)", "How much longer will you be cooking dinner?(The person has been cooking dinner for half an hour now)".

Comment: I think this question strays too far into "interpersonal skills" advice, so it's not really about learning English as such. Perhaps your question would have been better received if you'd asked how long before something in the oven was cooked and ready to serve.

Comment: I had no idea that such a question would be so difficult to give a detailed answer to.

Comment: "Have you nearly finished your tea?" "Is dinner nearly ready?" or "How long until dinner is ready?" As for the tennis, if they're playing a match it will take as long as it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When will you have finished [drinking] you tea*? is not there. It should be. **future perfect**.

The how long versions are not so idiomatic though we would say:

How long will you be playing tennis?

There's nothing grammatically wrong with any of them but using them requires particular circumstances. You do not need "for" in any case. 1) and 2) might work in situations wher the speaker is being ironic.

"So, John, I've getting fed up waiting for you. How long will you be drinking that tea?"
Answer: "I will have finished when the cows come home!"

Comment: Does choosing between the future simple and the future continuous have to do with whether the action has already started or not? I've heard that if an action, let's say, of repairing something has already started, you can't ask "When will they repair it?", only "When will they have repaired it?", so I wondered if I could ask "How long/much longer will you drink your tea (for)?" if the person is already drinking her tea, or only the continuous "How long/much longer will you be drinking your tea (for)?" is possible.

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov First, it's: How long will you be drinking your tea. No "for". Versus: How long will they drink tea in the mornings? It's like present simple and present continuous. Same idea.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, so my language has a completely different logic for using our aspects and, therefore, comparing the difference between the simple and continuous aspect in the future and in the past is not a good idea, I believe. Please reread my previous question.

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov I read brochures every day. I'm reading brochures every day. is similar to: I will read books every day [on holiday]; I will be reading books every day [on holiday]. The first states a factual intention the second emphasizes the **action** of reading.